# How to get value from result of asynctask to use in MainActivity

Tags: android-asynctask

I want to get the value of a and set to b,how can i do that?
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int a,b;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Task task=new Task();
    task.execute(5,6);
    b=a;
}

public class Task extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Integer>{

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
       super.onPostExecute(integer);
       a=integer;

   }

   @Override
   protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
       return integers[0]+integers[1];
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in line `b=a;` run on time running other thread

best result is in method `onPostExecute` write b = a;

so b before than a be set

Answer (score 0):

In your question you are already having the answer.
After executing this statement.

```
Task task=new Task();
task.execute(5,6);
```

After executing task.execute first `doInBackground` will be called and then it will return to `onPostExecute` then sum of a and b and your are assigning to a.
just write `b=a` in `onPostExecute` and it will work as your want.

Comment: thank for your answer but in this case i need to use b in the MainActivity.

Comment: can you explain your scenario because obviously Asyntask is going to take some time that's why we are using AsynTask but still you want in oncreate then create new thread and assign some time to execute but it will not cover your solution.

Comment: i have solved my problem by saving "a" on Sharedpreference then get back on MainActiviity and assign to "b" and i get the result i want.Thank for your help !\